# In Jmeter, how do I test a Map Value?

Tags: java, spring, jmeter, activiti

I'm testing a Spring Web Service with Jmeter. We're also using activiti, but since I'm a newb at both, that's about as far as I can tell. Supposedly, the application is to receive parameters from the request.

However, I hit a snag here (`UpdateInbdParams`):

```
private String taskId;

private Map<String, String> vars;

public String getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public Map<String, String> getVars() {
    return vars;
}

public void setVars(HashMap<String, String> vars) {
    this.vars = vars;
}
```

I'm supposed to send a string, and a Map. The latter is there so supposedly, we could send any parameters we need later, without modifying the code. But how do I test the latter, like this?

[image]

That returns this:

```
{"vars":null}
```

For reference, here's part of the code that bugs out:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public UpdateOutbdParams post(Locale locale, UpdateInbdParams model) {
    UpdateOutbdParams response = new UpdateOutbdParams();
    try{
        try{
            TaskService taskService = this.processEngine.getTaskService();
            Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(model.getTaskId()).singleResult();
            RuntimeService runtimeService = this.processEngine.getRuntimeService();
            /** ERRORS HERE **/
            runtimeService.setVariables(task.getExecutionId(), model.getVars());
            /** ERRORS END HERE **/
            taskService.complete(model.getTaskId());
            System.out.println(model.getVars().toString());
            System.out.println("Task execution id " + task.getExecutionId());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Inner catch: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Outer catch: "+ex.getMessage());
        return response;
    }
    return response;
}
```

And here's the actual error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myprojects.sample.api.txn.controllers.TxnTaskController.post(TxnTaskController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Inner catch: null
```

So I'm guessing it has something to do with how it (didn't) receive a Map value. Any ideas?

Thanks.